# Why I get 'None'

Tags: python, function, return, calculator, addition

```
from __future__ import division
from math import*

def add(*args):
    return sum(args)

def times(*args):
    s=1
    for i in range(len(args)-1):
        s*=args[i]*args[i+1]
    return s

def divide(*args):
    s=1
    for i in range(len(args)-1):
        s=args[i]/args[i+1]/s
    return s

def sqroot(arg):
    return sqrt(arg)

def get(data,s):
   if len(data)==1:
        s=add(s,int(data))
        return s

    s=add(s,int(data[data.index('+')-1]))
    cut=data[(data.index('+')+1):]
    get(cut,s)

user=raw_input()
print str(get(user,0))
```

Why does the function return `None` instead of the value of `s` *(if I print `s` the value is correct)*? The function simply resolves an expression like `1+1+1`.

Comment: Why I get 'None'? Dunno, may try a new aftershave or a different bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to return value in case when len > 1. Try this:

```
def get(data,s):
    if len(data) == 1:
        return add(s, int(data))

    s = add(s, int(data[data.index('+')-1]))
    cut = data[(data.index('+')+1):]
    return get(cut,s)
```

Also you need to think on string splitting, your indexing is not safe. You can take a look at the RPN or at least try something like(in case when you expr have only +):

```
add(*[int(x) for x in data.split('+')])
```